# GitLab CI-Build Artifacts command line download

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab-ci

GitLab version - 11.8.1 and trying to download the CI-Build artifacts zip file on terminal of Ubuntu -14.04-LTS system.

Using below command

```
curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:avxa_afdfouqernadfg" -o artifacts.zip https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/78/builds/artifacts/master/download?job=ci-build
```

command completed successfully, but while unzipping the artifacts.zip file getting below error.

```
Archive:  artifacts.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of artifacts.zip or
        artifacts.zip.zip, and cannot find artifacts.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Are you downloading single artefact using job id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your URL. It should be ***jobs*** instead of ***builds***:

```
curl -X GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:avxa_afdfouqernadfg" -o artifacts.zip "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/78/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=ci-build"
```

I also recommend to add a `-v` to your curl call, so you would have seen an error: `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive